# Why is the Rademacher complexity/distribution named after Hans Rademacher?

Tags: probability, terminology, math-history, rademacher-distribution

In machine learning theory, the Rademacher complexity of a function class $\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} \cF: X \mapsto \R$ over a particular set of inputs $x_{1:n} \in X^n$ is defined as
$$
\operatorname{R}(F, x_{1:n}) 
= 
\frac{1}{n}
   \E \left[
   \sup_{f \in F}
   \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_i f(x_i) 
\right],
$$
where $\sigma_i$ is a random variable distributed uniformly over $\{-1, +1\}$.

In machine learning literature [1], the Rademacher complexity is defined without etymology. The variable $\sigma_i$ is called a *Rademacher-distributed random variable*. However, in a biography of Rademacher [2], the words "distribution" and "random variable" do not occur. It seems that Rademacher was mainly a number theorist.

Why do these objects bear his name? From what I can tell, Rademacher did not introduce the definition $R$ above, and it seems strange to name $R$ after the distribution of $\sigma_i$ when $R$ itself is such a rich construct.

---

[1] Mehryar Mohri, Afshin Rostamizadeh, and Ameet Talwalkar. *Foundations of Machine Learning*. 2nd edition, MIT Press, 2018. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7voitv0vt24c88s/10290.pdf?dl=1

[2] Bruce C. Berndt. "Hans Rademacher (1892–1969)." *Acta Arithmetica LXI.3*, 1992. http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa61/aa6131.pdf.

Comment: It is not primarily the random variables $\epsilon_i$ uniformly distributed on $\{-1,1\}$ that are named after Rademacher, that is only a detail; more importantly, sums of the form $\sum \epsilon_i x_i$ are called Rademacher sums, and from there we name the random variable. I'm not sure yet why Rademacher sums are named after Rademacher, though.

Comment: This is rightly an hsm.se question. Also, why do you sometimes use $\sigma_i$ & sometimes $\epsilon_i$?

Comment: @J.G. typo, thanks